# Input String was not in correct format (CONVERTING STRING TO DECIMAL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, input, decimal

I am trying to convert the string from *.aspx page:

JaveScript:

```
function updateOnClick() {

        if (!toIgnore) {
            refNo = document.getElementById("txtRef").value;
            note1000 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_1000").value.substring(1));
            note100 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_100").value.substring(1));
            note50 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_50").value.substring(1));
            note20 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_20").value.substring(1));
            note10 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_10").value.substring(1));
            note5 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_5").value.substring(1));
            note2 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_2").value.substring(1));
            note1 = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtNote_1").value.substring(1));
            coins = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtCoins").value.substring(1));
            cheque = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtCheque").value.substring(1));
            outstanding = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtOutstanding").value.substring(1));
            total = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtTotal").value.substring(1));
            collectable = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtCollectable").value.substring(1));
            difference = removeCommas(document.getElementById("txtDifference").value.substring(1));
            collectionDate = document.getElementById(prefix + "txtDate").value;

            iniXmlHttp();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    if (responseText == "") {
                        loadDailyCollectionTable();
                        document.getElementById("txtRef").focus();
                        document.getElementById("txtRef").select();
                    }

                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "DailyCollectionPage.aspx?funcName=updateDailyCollection&RefNo=" + refNo +
            "&collectionDate=" + collectionDate + "&note1000=" + note1000 + "&note100=" + note100 +
            "&note50=" + note50 + "&note20=" + note20 + "&note10=" + note10 + "&note5=" + note5 +
            "&note2=" + note2 + "&note1=" + note1 + "&coins=" + coins + "&cheque=" + cheque +
            "&outstanding=" + outstanding + "&total=" + total + "&collectable=" + collectable + 
            "&difference=" + difference, true);

            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        else
            toIgnore = false;
    }
```

In Code Behind, I am getting the error in this line when I am trying to convert the string to decimal:

```
dailyCollection.Notes_1000 = Convert.ToDecimal(Request["note1000"]);
```

The error is: `INPUT STRING WAS NOT IN A CORRECT FORMAT.`

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code. Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried checking what you get in Request["note1000"] by simply converting it to string? may be the value you are getting is not decimal value, or possibly you might be getting a value that is something like garbage characters appended with decimal values. First check the value that you get. then you can decide for further steps

Comment: Whatz this `removeCommas` seems to be a culprit, also post the value available for `note1000`

Comment: What is the value in `Request["note1000"]`?

Comment: @V4Vendetta, Nice catch man! I used that function to remove commas, dollar signs, & other characters and pass the values as decimal. If the users key in 100 and press enter, the textbox will show $100.00. So `removeCommas()` function will remove those characters and return the decimal value. However, if the users enter 100 and straightaway click on the update button, that function has nothing to remove and return error as a wrong input format. Thanks for pointing out my problem.

Answer (score 2):

`INPUT STRING WAS NOT IN A CORRECT FORMAT.` Are you sure your code always returns `value` it never returns `NULL` ?
I think when your string is `Null` or `Empty` so you are receiving this error try to check for null or empty value first .

```
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.Tostring(Request["note1000"]))) 
{
   dailyCollection.Notes_1000 = Convert.ToDecimal(Request["note1000"].ToString());
```

Comment: +1 for your nice answer. But the error giving me the problem is because of JavaScript function, removeCommas, that I used inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this? -

```
dailyCollection.Notes_1000 = Convert.ToDecimal(Request["note1000"].ToString());
```

also, you should use [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) instead, which would handle such error conditions.

Eg:

```
decimal temp;
dailyCollection.Notes_1000  = Decimal.TryParse(Request["note1000"].ToString(),out temp)?temp:0.0M;
```